# Cannot show mysql data using jpa and thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf

I'm very new to Spring. I'm trying to build an user management web app.
Here is the controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class UserManagementController {
    @Autowired
    private UserManagementRepository userManagementRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(Model model){
        ArrayList<Staff> staffList = (ArrayList<Staff>) userManagementRepository.findAll();

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        modelAndView.setViewName("index");

        modelAndView.addObject("staffList", staffList);

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

The model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="staff")
@Data
public class Staff {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private int age;
    private String department;
    private String sex;
    private String status;
}
```

html file

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="staff, state : ${staffList}">
                        <td th.text="${staff.id}"></td>
                        <td th.text="${staff.name}"></td>
                        <td th.text="${staff.age}"></td>
                        <td th.text="${staff.department}"></td>
                        <td th.text="${staff.department}"></td>
                        <td th.text="${staff.status}"></td>
                    </tr>
```

and finally the application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_management
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

When i run the project, the table only shows the header and the body is totally blank.

Comment: Why are you using **state** variable there?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but can you try to make all attributes in model public or generate getters and then change your code like:

```
<td th.text="${staff.getId()}"></td>
```

Comment: They already have public getters and setters generated by Lombok `@Data` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 <tr th:each="staff : ${staffList}">
```

That will solve your problem If not then comment below and tell whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
<tr th:each="staff : ${staffList}">
    <td th:text="${staff.id}"></td>
    ...
</tr>
```

If it doesn't, look with a debugger if the value staffList in your controller is not empty or null. If it is, then you have an issue with your database connection or request.